# Way to automatically compress images pasted into Outlook emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, images, screenshot

My company limits our inbox size, and a large portion of my inbox seems to be made up of screenshots I've been sent by others or have pasted into emails myself - when I (or something sending to me) do a Control-V of a screeshot, it seems to save the result as a BMP (or something similarly large), and it results in a 5MB email.

I realize I can save the images as JPG/GIF/PNG and then attach the actual image to save space on my outgoing messages, but when people send a screenshot to me, I'm stuck with a huge email. Are there any Outlook add-ins or other tools that could go through my inbox and process all the images in my email to convert them to JPG? Alternatively, something that works automatically on my outgoing messages and compresses images it finds into a pre-determined format - this way, even if somebody does email me a 5MB image, my reply will compress it and it will stay that way for the rest of the conversation (resulting in a 6MB conversation instead of 30MB).

I realize the new Outlook "Cleanup" feature mitigates this somewhat by removing redundant segments of emails, including the included images, but it still keeps at least one copy around and I'd prefer it compress even that.

Thanks and hopefully there's something out there! PS - I'm not opposed to something I have to pay for.

Comment: Do you actually need to keep all these emails? Half of my 'outlook help' work seems to be tasks like creating a .pst for all emails older than 4 years and archiving mail in them. That way it is not on the exchange server, local .ost files as smaller (and faster and easier to backup) and everything feels cleaner.

Comment: @Hennes: The answer is generally "no", and I delete where I can, but the mail server size restrictions mean I have to be extra-vigilant about it. Also, there are cases where I want to keep an email chain but not the screenshot, and I can't delete an inline screenshot - I can remove an attachment (from an HTML email, for example), but if the user sends the email as "Rich Text" then the image is pasted directly in the email and can't be removed.